# How do I save all the stored information on my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I need to do a factory reset to my iPhone 4, but don't know how to save my stored information such as my Contacts, Pictures, and Purchased apps.

Answer (score 1):

Apple makes backing up iOS devices easy. Just make a backup of it with iTunes or iCloud, as detailed in [this Apple guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977).

For Photos, just use the Photos app to import them all to your Mac. If you're using a Windows machine, open My Computer, double-click whatever represents your iPhone and copy the folder marked "DCIM" to your computer.